# Why on average, is $A[j]$ smaller than half of the elements of $A[1\dots j]$

Tags: statistics, algorithms, average

This is a phrase from the book "Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd edition page 28.

> Suppose that we randomly choose $n$ numbers and apply insertion sort. How long does it take to determine where in subarray $A[1\dots j-1]$ to insert element $A[j]$? On average, half the elements in $A[1\dots j-1]$ are less than $A[j]$, and half the elements are greater. On average, therefore, we check half of the subarray $A[1\dots j-1]$, and so $t_j$ is about $\frac{j}{2}$.

I can't comprehend why on average, $A[j]$ is bigger than half of the elements of $A[1\dots j-1]$. For $A[j]$ to be bigger than half of elements of $A[1\dots j-1]$, shouldn't it be the average value of the elements of $A[1\dots j-1]$? How do we know that $A[j]$ is the average value for the average case? I might be confused on the English language level, not on the mathematical level but English is not my primary language. So please take that into account.

Comment: 2 is bigger than half the preceding elements in the sequence (1,999,2). But 2 is clearly not equal to 500, which is the average value of the elements 1 and 999.

Comment: You are correct that it will be very rare for half the preceding values to be greater and half to be smaller (this would only happen when $A[j]$ is the median) but that's not what the paragraph is saying.  Rather, it's saying the expected number of elements that are smaller than $A[j]$ is half the total number

Comment: I forgot to ask this in the bounty message, but is "on average" instead referring to the average ***over all stages*** of the sort? So, if there are $n$ elements in our array, then averaging over all $n$ stages of the sort, $A[j]$ is greater than 50% of $A[1..j - 1]$. **Is this correct? How do I reconcile this with $E(X)$ above?**

Comment: @user51462 Maybe a clearer way to think about is that the element you're putting into the right position in the current iteration has no dependence on the elements before it. This isn't very rigorous, but this then means there's an equal probability of inserting at the $n$th element from the beginning and the $n$th element from the end, so the expected position should be half of the way through the previous elements (i.e. the sorted sublist).

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are a couple of things going on in the passage in the book.
One is the implicit acceptance of standard assumptions for this kind of problem rather than explicitly stating those assumptions.
Another is (likely) that the results of this paragraph are meant only to be used in a later asymptotic analysis, in which case some kinds of inaccuracy are irrelevant and can be ignored.

To "randomly choose $n$ numbers" is quite a vague concept. What is the random distribution of these numbers? This may be confusing and is not well explained in this particular passage of the book.

An alternative model is, we have a set of numbers to be sorted, and they are delivered in a random sequence. It turns out that if you take any continuous real-valued distribution and you have $n$ independent random variables with that distribution,
with probability $1$ you have $n$ distinct values and every permutation of the sequence of values is equally likely. But you don't actually need to consider whether such a model actually works as I said. You could just as well consider a well-shuffled deck of cards, and assume that the passage in the book is talking about the first $j$ cards in the shuffled deck.

Looking at the first $j$ cards in the deck, one of them sorts to the first place in the set of $j$ cards, one sorts to the second place, another sorts to the third place, and so forth. If the card are thoroughly shuffled before the sort begins,
then every permutation of those $j$ cards is equally likely, which implies that each of those $j$ cards is equally likely to have originally been in the $j$th place in the shuffled deck. That is why there is probability $1/j$ that $j$th card in the shuffled deck is inserted in the first position in the sorted set of $j$ cards, and likewise the probability is $1/j$ for the $i$th position, $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, j$.

That is, the sorted position of the $j$th unsorted card among the first $j$ unsorted cards is uniformly distributed from $1$ to $j$. This is a symmetric distribution, so the probability that $i$ cards come before this card is the same as the probability that $i$ cards come after. So if $X$ is the number of cards that that are before the $j$th unsorted card when we insert it, and $Y$ is the number of cards that come after,
$E(X) = E(Y)$. But $X + Y = j - 1$ always, so $E(X) + E(Y) = E(X + Y) = j - 1$.
It follows that $E(X) = (j - 1)/2$.

You can also compute $E(X)$ using the uniform distribution from $0$ to $j - 1$ and one of the usual formulas for expected value, but this has already been done in another answer so I won't repeat it.

The key point here is that when the book says "on average", this has nothing to do with the average value of the first $j - 1$ or $j$ numbers in the unsorted list.
It is only about the average of $t_j$, which is apparently equal to the number of elements of the list that come before the original value of $A[j]$ when we have sorted the first $j$ elements.

As to why the value of $t_j$ should be "about $j/2$" and not $(j-1)/2$ "on average,"
my guess is this is because the author considers the missing term $-1/2$ negligible in the final calculation where $t_j$ is to be used.

---

Some comments on the words "on average":

I'm fairly sure that "On average, therefore, we check half of the subarray" refers to an average over all possible initial permutations of the data.
It cannot be an average over stages because $j/2$ refers to the size of whichever stage you are on.

Secondly, "on average" refers to the mean value of some random variable, in this case the proportion of elements of $A[1\ldots(j-1)]$ that are smaller than $A[j]$. Saying that we get a particular result "on average" does not assert that this particular result is likely; it merely says that this particular value is the mean probabilistic value of all possible results.
For example, if we choose a number uniformly from the integers from $1$ to $999$, "on average" the result will be $500$, even though the probability that we choose the exact number $500$ is only $1/999$.

Comment: I think you are assuming $P(X_1 \leq X_i, X_2 \leq X_i,...,X_{i-1} \leq X_i) = \prod_j P(X_j \leq X_i)$ which need not be true. Can u mathematically write out equations similar to my answer and impose ordering on deck of cards similar to numbers and prove ? and make the assumptions mathematical ? Thanks man ! Cheers !

Comment: I am not doing that at all. The individual events $X_1 \leq X_j$ and $X_2 \leq X_j$ are very clearly not independent; however, when a list of $j$ sorted items is randomly permuted (all permutations equally likely) each element of the original list has an equal chance of being at the end of the permuted list. If you want to choose the original values randomly via iid continuous random variables, then each $X_i$ has an equal chance to be the $k$th statistic of $X_1,\ldots,X_j$ for $1\leq k\leq j$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My point is every random variable has an equal chance of being in $i^{th}$ position but for each $i$, chances are different. For example choose from $1:N$, being the smallest among $j$ random choices has a different probability than being in the middle and being the largest. I feel being in the middle has large chances than being smallest for a particular $j^{th}$ random variable. What we want is probability $X_j$ for a fixed $j$ being in $i^{th}$ position which is unequal for different $i$. I think to settle this, better to write down the probabilities. Cheers !

Comment: I think you are randomizing over $j$ also. Dont do that and prove.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "a particular $j$th random variable." If you know the value of that variable and you know the distribution, you can talk about the conditional probability of being in the $i$th place. But this problem is about prior probabilities, not conditional probabilities. And the prior probabilities are most definitely equal if the variables are iid.

Comment: I don't have time to write it up at the moment, but the $1/j$ probability can be derived by the use of indicator variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are $j$ positions where we can insert $A[j]$: Before $A[1]$, between $A[1]$ and $A[2]$, ... after $A[j - 1]$. Name the position as $k \in \{0, ..., i-1\}$.

Assume that the position is randomly chosen (means: every position with equal probability, ,,uniformly distributed").
Consider the random variable $X: k \mapsto $ number of elements smaller than k.

Calculate the expectation value of $X$:
$E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} P(X=k) k = \sum  \frac{1 }{ i } k = \frac1i \cdot (i-1)i/ 2 $ (Gauss' formula).

This is $(i-1)/2$, with other words: inserting at a random position implies that the expectation value of the random variable ,,number of elements less than" is $(i-1)/2$. (Up to calculation errors ...)

The average value is the expectation value in the finite case.

Answer (score 0):

> Say we were sorting an array of 5 elements containing the numbers 1,
> 2, 3, 4 and 5 in some order. - If we're on the final iteration, then
> elements A[1..4]  are sorted and we have only A[5]  remaining to be
> inserted. In that case, the statement "A[5] is less than half the
> elements and greater than the other half" is only true when A[5]=3,
> which happens in only in 24 of the possible 120 permutations, i.e. 20%
> of the time. And this number gets smaller as we increase the size of
> the array.

Totally exact.
But what we need is a little different. We don't ask for the most frequent value, or  one value which would be always reached, but we need to estimate the average of the rank.

A[5] is less than $0$ element in 24 of the possible 120 permutations,

A[5] is less than $1$ element in 24 of the possible 120 permutations,

A[5] is less than $2$ elements in 24 of the possible 120 permutations,

A[5] is less than $3$ elements in 24 of the possible 120 permutations,

A[5] is less than $4$ elements in 24 of the possible 120 permutations,

Average of 0,1,2,3,4, all with factors $24$ gives $2$. The average is $2$.

In average, A[5] is less than $2$ elements. No, sorry, the correct formulation is a little different : the average of the count of elements greater than A[5] is $2$.

With one more element, we obtain a result which is not an integer, so the correct formulation is more obvious :

With $6$ elements, we have $720$ combinations ; the average of the count of elements greater than A[6] is $2.5$

Edit : Balaji sb suggests there is a problem when all values are not distinct.

If we consider that some values may be identical, we need a FAIR rule to treat identical values.

When we count the number of elements greater than A[6], we need to say :

- if A[i] is strictly greater than A[6], count +1
- if A[i] is equal to  A[6], count +0.5
- if A[i] is less than A[6], count +0, of course.

With this rule , the results are still valid. The average of numbers greater than A[6] is 2.5 if we consider that a number equal to A[6] is counted as half.

This is the only fair rule.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer but my point is a sample point corresponding to a permutation in which $A[1] \leq A[2]$ can be equal to a sample point corresponding to a permutation in which $A[1] \geq A[2]$ if at the sample point $A[1] = A[2]$. So when you count the permutations the sample point set for each permutation are not disjoint. So you cannot add these counts of permutations directly. where a sample point is a set of random numbers picked which will satisfy the permutation. May be i am missing something. Edit your answer if you feel i have a valid point. Thanks man ! Cheers !

Comment: Anyway assuming distinct values of $A[1],A[2],...$ , i have rewrote my answer. I get the same answer as you. If you do not assume distinct ness of $A[1],A[2],...$ then things seem to get complicated quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Let $A_{1},...,A_{{j-1}}$ be $j-1$ randomly picked numbers from $[-N,N]$.

Let $X$ be a new $j^{th}$ random picked number appearing at $i^{th}$ position.

$$P(X \  is \  in \  i^{th} \  position) =  \sum_{S : S \subseteq [j-1], |S| = i-1} P(max_S (A_{j}) \leq X, max_{[j-1] \setminus S} (A_{j}) \geq X )$$
$$= {j-1 \choose i-1} \times P(max_S (A_{j}) \leq X, max_{[j-1] \setminus S} (A_{j}) \geq X )$$
where $S = [1,i-1]$.

Above is very general. Now assuming all $A_1,...,A_{j-1},X$ are distinct we have, from steps of above derivation:
$$P(X \  is \  in \  i^{th} \  position) = \frac{(j-1)!}{(i-1)! (j-i)!} \times P(max_S (A_{j}) \leq X, max_{[j-1] \setminus S} (A_{j}) \geq X )$$

$$= \frac{(j-1)!}{(i-1)! (j-i)!}  \frac{{2N+1 \choose j} \times (i-1)! \times (j-i)!}{{2N+1 \choose j} j!} = 1/j $$.

Hence, Expected Value =  $\sum_{i=1}^j i P(X \  is \  in \  i^{th} \  position) = \sum_{i=1}^j i \times 1/j = \frac{j-1}{2}$

The assumption $A_1,...,A_{j-1},X$ are distinct is critical to above simple derivation. If we do not assume distinctness, things get complicated.

Comment: I think we have dealt with my earlier comments, so I deleted them. You are correct that it causes a big complication if two different variables in the list can have the same value with non-zero probability. As soon as you allow that possibility, the simple argument for $1/j$ no longer works. I think any reasonable model with a discrete distribution will favor either smaller values of $i$ (if the $i$th position is defined by $<$) or greater values of $i$ (if the $i$th position is defined by $\leq$).